# You can have_one if you're true

Tags: ruby, activerecord

In my website (written with sinatra) I am trying to set up a database. I have 2 tables, here referred to as Table1 and Table2.

models.rb

```
class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    Table1.where(bool:true) has_one :table2 # PSUDO-CODE
    # So that every record where bool:true has the relationship
    # but every record where bool:false or bool:nil doesn't
end
class Table2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :table1
end
```

I am trying to find a way to make the section labeled `PSUDO-CODE` into actual code. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no section labeled pseudo-code. But the question isn't clear anyway. The tables will always be the same; what's different is whether or not there actually *is* a relationship between an instance of table1 and table2.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry about that I was just editing the `PSUDO-CODE` section in. In terms of the rest of your comment, I would like to be able to have each `table2` instance correspond to a `table1` instance, but not vice versa.

Comment: I think there's a disconnect with how RDBMS work and your current thought process: the tables don't change based on values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly: a class either has a relationship or it doesn't (although of course there may be no associated record)

You can set conditions on an association, but to the best of my knowledge you can only really set conditions on the associated collection (i.e. table 2 in this case)

You can however override the generated method, so for example

```
class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :table2
  def table2(*args)
    bool ? super : nil
  end
end
```

This works with current versions of activerecord - not how far back this is supported (older version defined the association methods directly on the class so you couldn't call super)

Comment: In the question I say that "my website [is] (written with sinatra)". Will this work with sinatra as well as rails?

Comment: You can substitute 'current versions of rails' with 'current versions of active record'. The sinatra version is not relevant

Comment: So then `table2` is defined as a function? And your solution is to redefine that function such that in the class `Table1`,  `table2` is defined as `Table1.where(bool:true)`? I'm just a little confused at how your answer works.

Comment: Not quite. When you do `some_instance_of_table_1.table2` you're always calling a function (generated by rails). I'm just overriding that method to check your boolean attribute first.

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you very much!